# trying to move the files uploaded using input type file to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move the files to the drop area if I opt to choose the files from input type file which is a multiple input field.

I have the code for the dropzone like this:

```
var target = document.getElementById('dropArea');

target.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

target.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    files = event.dataTransfer.files, numFiles = files.length;
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < numFiles; i++) {
        var uploadForm = new FormData();
        var fType = (files[i].type);
        if (fType == 'image/jpeg' || fType == 'image/gif' || 
            fType == 'image/jpeg' || fType == 'image/jpg' || 
            fType == 'image/png' || fType == 'image/bmp') {

            uploadForm.append("theFile", files[i]);
            uploadForm.append("fileName", files[i].name);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, true);

            function transferComplete(event) {
                $('.alert-info').hide();
                $('.alert-success').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            }

            $('.alert-info').fadeIn();
            xhr.open("post", "com/processupload.cfc?method=uploaddata", true);
            xhr.send(uploadForm);
        } else {
            $('.alert-error').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    }
}, false);
```

I have another input field called as `<input type="file" name="browse" multiple" id='files">`

I want that when I upload using this button, it should immediately move all files to the dropzone area and that will get triggered instantly when it receives items.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `#files` input to trigger `#dropArea`'s drop listener when files are selected/changed. To do this you need two things:

First, add the `onChange` attribute to the `#files` input that will execute a function created in the next step:

```
<input type="file" name="browse" multiple" id="files" onChange="triggerDrop()">
```

Second, create the function so it is available to `onChange`:

```
function triggerDrop() {
  var dropEvent = new Event('drop');
  target.dispatchEvent(dropEvent);
}
```

The two lines in `triggerDrop` simply create a drop event (since that's what you want to trigger on the other input) and manually execute it. This will run the code you wrote inside `target`'s drop event listener.